# Extract the unique genres and its count and store in data frame with index key

Tags: r, data-science, analytics

How do you split the multiple values of a variable in R programming.
[image: Image with column Genre]Like, in the image the genre has multiple values in it's cells. how do you separate them and get count of the values in a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
table(trimws(unlist(strsplit(df$Genre, split = ","))))
```

Comment: This was perfect. It also trimmed unwanted space. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `separate_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
  separate_rows(Genre) %>%
  count(Genre)
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
table(unlist(strsplit(df$Genre, ",\\s*")))
```

Comment: @ShravyaReddy this trimmed the unwanteed space with `\\s*`

Comment: Yeah, but, I had Genre values  "Action" and other with space "    Action".
It was considered as two rows using the '\\s*', whereas, by using trimws, it eliminated the initial space and gave correct count by considering them as same.